# Problems automating sftp with expect

Tags: automation, sftp, expect

I'm trying to automate data transfer using sftp.

I have a hacky expect script that grabs the data file.  Unfortunately, partway through transfer the file is unexpectedly truncated.  When I tried doing the same command by hand it always transfers the whole file.

The first line of my expect script is:

```
spawn  sftp -o ConnectTimeout=120 username@boxAddress
```

I was under the impression that putting "-o ConnectTimeout=120" would prevent the connection from timing out if it stalled for less than two minutes.

What should I do to get the script to download the whole file?

Another, much less important question:
I would prefer to authenticate using keys (but this isn't essential as I'm only grabbing data from the external server).  I don't think I could put a key on this external server (because it is not under my control), but (when I used FileZilla to connect to it) I noticed that FileZilla accepted a key from it.  How could I setup my script to ask for and use this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `expect` script just to grab some files over SFTP; the same can be done from command line:

```
sftp username@boxAddress:/path/to/datafile
```

will fetch `datafile` to the current directory.

---

To answer the second question (which should've been [posted separately](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)), you are confusing two different kinds of keys.

- When FileZilla or `sftp` *accept* a key *from* the server, it is the "**host** key", used for verifying the *server's* identity.
- When you use a key for authentication, it is the **user** authentication key, used for verifying *your* identity.

Usually, you do *not* need any additional control over the server to enable the latter; simply append your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This can be done in any way, including SFTP `get` and `put`.

Comment: I DO need some kind of script (doesn't have to be expect) for automating the sftp transfer.  Currently it is done manually (by someone who uses FileZilla) and I want to make it automatic.

Comment: @DanShriver: What I was trying to say is that you don't need to wrap interactive-mode `sftp` within `expect`; you can just call a single non-interactive `sftp` command

Comment: That's a slight problem: to do non-interactive I have to use the keys.  I have a username / pwd pair for an account but it isn't me, so I can't even check their /home/username/.ssh folder to see if they have a key.  I guess I need to look into creating an account for me on the box I'm trying to get data from.

Comment: @DanShriver: You "cannot check" because of technical or policy reasons?

Comment: When I do "ls" on that directory I get "permission denied".  I can view the parent /home/<username> directory though.

Comment: @DanShriver: Can you connect using interactive SSH, and run `ls -ld` on the `.ssh` directory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2494/discussion-between-dan-shriver-and-grawity)

Comment: Fixed by using cURL.  Needed to get cURL with version > 7.16.0 and be compiled with libssh2.  Then switched from "expect" to cURL and things worked.